# generate struct with macro if function is called?

Tags: rust, macros, code-generation

I'm making a builder pattern for a struct that can have any number of generics.

The core idea is that I have multiple structs, and I can use a builder pattern to create the next one. Something like :

```rust
struct EmptyBuilder {}

impl EmptyBuilder {
    fn add_generic<T>(self) -> Builder1<T>;
}

struct Builder1<T1> {}

impl<T1> Builder1<T1> {
    fn add_generic<T2>(self) -> Builder2<T1, T2>;
}

struct Builder2<T1, T2> {}
```

Now, this feels like a good place for macros. Ideally, I could generate the builders procedurally. The issue is, I don't know how many the user will create. I could dump a bunch of them, and whenever I need more add more, but in my case I have two types of generics (imagine structs like `Builder<T1, T2, U1, T3, U2, U3>`) where order is important, and this can quickly come to lot of code generation and macro invocation.

Now, I was wondering if there was a way to call the macro invocation only if the builder method is called ? so that the `Builder2<T1, T2>` is created only if `EmptyBuilder::add_generic` is called ?

Comment: Macros operate at the syntax level, so no. The closest you could get is to use a cargo feature to enable `add_generic` when they want to use it.

Comment: @PitaJ Thanks. I'll go with lots of macro calls and features to add more then.